# preventDefault() not working after editing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="artikelen">
 <div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://mijnmanege.nl/img/artikelen/1.png" alt="Article" />
  </div>
  <strong>Article</strong>
  <span>{artikel_groep} (<span data-artikel-groep-id="1">1</span>)</span>
  <img src="/img/v3/main/icons/geld.png" alt="Price" /> 999
  <form method="post">
   <input type="number" value="1" name="aantal" max="99" min="1" required="required" data-artikel-id="1" data-artikel-groep-id="1" />
   <input type="submit" value="Buy" name="submit" />
  </form>
 </div>
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.artikelen form').submit(function(e) {
  alert('We are in!');
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

When I press the submit I get the "We are in" alert and the form gets prevented from being submitted. However when I use $('.artikelen').html(code...); to add exactly the same html code to the class artikelen (without the first  and the last  ofcourse), it still gets submitted and doesn't even trigger the error.

The console doens't give any errors whatsoever.

Thanks in advance.

And sorry for any bad English, I'm not a native.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are repacing the form so the event binding is gone, you could use delegate to solve that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on('submit', '.artikelen form', function(e) {
  alert('We are in!');
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```